# Debug Externally Called Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I'm debugging this line of code:

```
var myDict = myEnumerable.ToDictionary(k => k.NumericValue, v => v.Display());
```

I get an `ArgumentException (An item with the same key has already been added)`.

VS2012 does not seem to provide insight as to what value of `k.NumericValue` resulted in the duplicate key.

I can certainly solve this by writing some additional debug code to get at the duplicate key, but is there a way to get that directly from the debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to have the symbol information for `ToDictionary`, and I rather doubt that the .NET BCL is compiled in debug mode... so no.

Of course, if you write your own `ToDictionary` implementation you could provide the information in the exception, or be able to break at points where the information is available.

While it might be technically possible to inspect the various states of memory to try to ascertain what the key is while this program is running, it's going to be *far* easier to just change the code a bit instead to diagnose this issue.

Comment: You are right. It would be possible and trivial if the Watch supported lambda expression but it's more quicker to add a line of code like `myEnumerable.GroupBy(e => e.NumericValue, e => e.NumericValue).Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1).Select(grp => grp.First())` and inspect the result.

Comment: Normally I would have just changed the code and moved on, but the process runs quite a while before hitting that condition so it got me thinking about whether there is a better way.  If it were possible to inspect `k` in the debugger at the point the ArgumentException is thrown, that would solve the problem.

Comment: @SimonBelanger You can get the debugger to break on the lambda, the problem is that the lambda has already completed execution by the time the exception is thrown, so by the time there is an exception it's too late to get at the value through the lambda; there is simply a local in the library code holding onto the result, so you need to be able to inspect that local in the definition of `ToDictionary`, which can't really be done.

Comment: @EricJ. See my comment to Simon for a bit more details on why this can't really be done.

Comment: @Servy What I meant is if you break on the line, it would be simpler if we could run a lambda expression in the watch window.

Comment: @Simon: Even if you could run the lamda expression, what *value* would you provide?  It is only helpful to debug the state of the lamda expression with the values provided by `ToDictionary()`.

Comment: @EricJ. Watching for `myEnumerable.GroupBy(e => e.NumericValue, e => e.NumericValue).Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1).Select(grp => grp.First()).ToArray()` would give you the list of duplicated keys. The values passed to `ToDictionary` are coming directly from `myEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

Servy's answer is correct for the *question* I asked.

The *solution* is to write custom code to debug.  Here is an extension method I wrote as a drop-in replacement for `ToDictionary()` that throws a more meaningful exception.  Feel free to edit and improve.

```
public static Dictionary<K,V> ToDictionaryDbg<T,K,V>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T,K> key, Func<T,V> value)
{
    if (source == null) return null;

    Dictionary<K, V> result = new Dictionary<K, V>();

    foreach (var element in source)
    {
        K k = default(K);
        V v = default(V);

        try
        {
            k = key(element);
            v = value(element);
            result.Add(k, v);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException aex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Could not add element with key " + k + ". See inner exception.", aex);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```